# Complex numbers: negative absolute value (radius)?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I need to find a complex number that represented by the following poler representation:

($\mathbb r$, $\theta$) = ($-5$, $\pi \over 2$)

My question is: how is a negative radius (absolute value) possible?

What does it mean \ sign?

Comment: It is not possible, at least not under the usual, standard definitions. Check this carefully.

Comment: I've seen things like this before; when I've encountered it, it has just meant to take the radius in the opposite direction. So, normally we would expect this to correspond to the point $5i$ in the complex plane (or $(0,5)$ if we identify it with $\Bbb R^2$. However, with the negative, it will correspond to $-5i$. I'm not going to say this is how it is for you, just when I've encountered it previously.

Comment: @Clayton The $\theta$ signs the angle with the positive X Axis, doesn't it?

Comment: @user1798362: I'm not sure what you mean by signs the angle with the positive $x$-axis. The angle begins at $0^\circ$ there and rotates counterclockwise through an angle of $\pi/2$ in your case.

Comment: @Clayton Ok, thank you!! I have addition question and I'll better and it here instead of another ask: if $\theta$ = 45, than `a = b` in case $\mathbb z$ = `a + bi`?

Comment: @user1798362: You should post that as a new question, making the question a little more clear.

Comment: @Clayton:"...to take the radius in the opposite direction"...opposite to **what**?

Comment: @DonAntonio: As I've always imagined these graphs drawn, I find the angle of the point, and draw the line connecting the origin to that point (an invisible line) away from the origin. With a negative radius, one draws it in precisely the reverse direction.

Comment: @Clayton Ok, that's was a tricky question - and the answer about is "The pair (-5, $\pi \over 2$) isn't represent a polar expression", because r >=  0. thank you all.

Comment: @user1798362: Glad to hear it! That is best answer that could be provided.

Comment: I see, @Clayton. Thanks, though I'd say that if we have angles then we don't really need all that direction stuff with signs...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I agree. I also have noticed some old high school textbooks aren't as formal as they should be (hence my previous experience with the notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta$$